# Windows Update is downloading updates when it is supposed to notify me first

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

I have Windows XP SP2, and Windows Update is set to notify me that updates are available and not download any updates.

However, recently, the yellow shield in the system tray has appeared indicating that updates are downloading.

I have gone into the Windows Security centre and confirmed updates are set to notify only, and not download.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Move first to SP3, ASAP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be getting pushed emergency out of band updates...these typically disregard policy.

Comment: True and SP2 is at the end of it's support cycle.